# Create logical volume again on Ubuntu after deleating it

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, partition, server-setup

I have a Ubuntu 16.04 Server and used these two commands which accidently deleted my logical volume:

`lvchange -an -v /dev/sda5/xyz-vg`
and 
`lvremove -vf /dev/sda5/xyz-vg`

I did so from an Ubuntu Live CD, in order to decrease the size of the partition where the lv was located using `gparted`. It would not work otherwise. In the end resizing  worked fine, but now I cannot boot anymore.

At startup I get an error message `Failed to find logical volume "xyz-vg/root"`

`sudo pvdisplay` from the live CD indicates that the PV is called `/dev/sda5` and the VG name is `xyz-vg`.

`sudo lvmdiskscan` gives me that I have three partitions of which one is a `LVM phyiscal volume`.

I followed steps indicated as linked in the comment section [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/263741/recovering-accidentally-destroyed-lvm2-information/264580):

1. pvcreate --restorefile /etc/lvm/archive/ --uuid dev/sdX
2. vgcfgrestore -f /etc/lvm/archive/ --verbose thisVG
3. vgdisplay -v /dev/thisVG && vgchange -ay /dev/thisVG
4. mount /dev/thisVG/missingLV /mnt

This recreated my volume group. The output of `vgdisplay` from the livecd is now:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               xzy-vg
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  9
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                0
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               439.45 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              112499
  Alloc PE / Size       0 / 0   
  Free  PE / Size       112499 / 439.45 GiB
  VG UUID               Ii03eE-fP5g-1Mjm-yC0T-F9Yl-5vqW-XYUBID
```

However, this still does not bring me back the logical volume. `lvdisplay` gives no output, so I guess I need to recreate it? How do I do that without deleting all the data that is still on the disk?

Comment: The lvremove command does not temporarily deactivate a logical volume. It _destroys_ it.

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question, which also has an answer that will work for you: https://serverfault.com/questions/263741/recovering-accidentally-destroyed-lvm2-information/264580

Comment: @Spooler Please click the "close" link above to mark a question as a duplicate.